# How to display 2 widgets on the same space?

Tags: layout, qt4

I have this main window on which I would like to put 2 widgets on the same space, i.e. when the user clicks a button then one of the widgets should come up front and the other be hidden and then change places when clicking another button.

My Widget are of different types: one is a QGLWidget and the other one is a QGraphicsView.

How could I put these 2 widgets on the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html). Qt Doc says that :

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one
>   widget is visible at a time.